# Scala spark Read CSV with comma as decimal separator

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

i try to read a csv in databrick(spark scala) whit comma (,) as decimal separator.
I use badRecordsPath option to catch bad record in a specified path so i can't read it as string then replace "," with ".".

I try ro read csv but i have the following error: "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0,939".

It's means that number with "," as decimal separator can't be read as Float.

my code is a simple spark read with a schema :

```
val schema = new StructType()
.add("mycolumn1","float")
.add("mycolumn2","int")
.add("mycolumn3","timestamp")
```

And the read :

```
spark.read
.options(Map("inferSchema"->"false","delimiter"->";","header"->"true", "timestampFormat" ->"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm","badRecordsPath" -> path to save bad records))
.schema(schema)
.csv(path to csv)
```

Anybody has a idea of how i can read it as float ?

Comment: can we see code example you tried added to this question?

Comment: it is a simple spark.read. i just edit the post to add the code

Comment: I guess you just answer your question, you are using delimiter ";" but data got delimiter ","

Comment: delimiter ";" is for column delimiter. My problem is that i have float column in this format "0,939" but spark can't read it as a float column. Spark can only read this format ("0.939")

Comment: For reading, you can change "mycolumn1" type to "string". After reading, column type can be changed: df.withColumn("mycolumn1", [convert logic here])

Comment: Add data snapshot for clear picture to the questions, thanks.

Comment: @pasha701 i know i can read as string then change the type but am using badRecordsPath to get bad records data. If i read as string maybe some bad records will not be recognize. As i said in my question i can't read it as string then replace "," with "." Am looking for a other way.

Comment: you don't have other choice as Spark doesn't have corresponding option.  `badRecordPath` will help you to handle other columns, bug for float numbers you need to perform parsing yourself, and then filter out the entries where number is null